# Combining multiple data readers into one

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have some code (C#/ADO.NET) where I get 2 or more readers (**IDataReader** instances) - each of which could be a reader on multiple datasets meant to be enumerated through the **NextResult** API.

My task is to combine these into a single reader and return it to my caller, so that they can enumerate all the different results through this single reader - calling **NextResult** as necessary.

(Note that each of these datasets have different kinds of data.).

Seems like a valid use case. There should be some way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the fun of it I tried creating a class, below. It would definitely be a hassle to test.

Before explaining why it would be a pain, I'll offer you an excuse for saving yourself the trouble. If your class is creating `IDataReader`s, there's likely not a good reason to pass them to the caller. You can just read the data from them and pass *that* to the caller. Is there any good reason why the callers need readers and not just the actual data? Opening a datareader and closing it is something you want to accomplish without getting too many hands in the process, so if you can open it, get what you need, and then close it, that's ideal.

When we advance from one result set to the next within an `IDataReader` it's usually in the context of making a single call, so it's easier to follow what the result sets are. We just called procedure XYZ, it returns two result sets, so we have to check for both result sets. I wouldn't want to deal with an `IDataReader` that had lots and lots of result sets, especially when it's a bunch of smaller ones artificially combined. You'd have to keep track of a lot of result sets and switch between different methods for reading them since they contain different columns.

And there's also the issue of those open connections. We usually close a connection when we're done with a reader. But now it's less clear when that connection would get closed. How do you know which connection belongs to which reader? What if you close the connection for a reader while a different reader is still using it?

So here's a rough idea of what it might look like. I obviously didn't test this. You would have to keep track of which one is current and handle advancing to the next reader if `NextResult` is called and there isn't a next result within the current reader. And you'd have to close the readers and make sure they all get disposed. This could be tested, but just the testing would be a headache, and that's often a good warning not to do something.

```
public class AggregateDataReader : IDataReader
{
    private readonly Queue<IDataReader> _readers;
    private IDataReader _current;

    public AggregateDataReader(IEnumerable<IDataReader> readers)
    {
        _readers = new Queue<IDataReader>(readers);
    }

    private bool AdvanceToNextReader()
    {
        _current?.Dispose();
        var moreReaders = _readers.Any();
        if (moreReaders) _current = _readers.Dequeue();
        return moreReaders;
    }

    public bool NextResult()
    {
        if (_current == null) return false;
        if (_current.NextResult()) return true;
        return AdvanceToNextReader();
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        return _current.Read();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _current?.Dispose();
        while (_readers.Any()) _readers.Dequeue().Dispose();
    }

    public string GetName(int i)
    {
        return _current.GetName(i);
    }

  ... lots of these...

    public byte GetByte(int i)
    {
        return _current.GetByte(i);
    }

    public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
    {
        return _currentGetBytes(i, fieldOffset, buffer, bufferoffset, length);
    }

   ... etc...

    public void Close()
    {
        _current?.Close();
        while (_readers.Any()) _readers.Dequeue().Close();
    }

   ... etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the pitfalls and will watch out for them. It just seems like a complex but valid use case for which there should be a solution like yours already built.